# How to check weather created custom dispatchque is already in progress

Tags: ios

How to check weather que1 is already in progress if  dispatch_async function block takes too long to finish.

```
-(void)downloadImageFromURL:(NSString*)_imageURl
{

dispatch_queue_t que1 = dispatch_queue_create("abcd", NULL)
dispatch_async(que1, ^{

    @autoreleasepool {
        NSData *imagedata=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:
                           [NSURL URLWithString:_imageURl]];


        image = [UIImage imageWithData:imagedata];
        if (image)
        {
            [imagedata writeToFile:imagePath atomically:YES];
        }

    }

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        NSLog(@"DONE");            
    });

});
}
```

Ex: if i will call **downloadImageFromURL:** method twice it with same url it will execute twice...how to stop 2nd time execution....plz help

Comment: what the use of `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        NSLog(@"DONE");            
    });` in here

Comment: There is now such use here but whenever current task get done, you will receive callback in this method and after that you can work on main thread with executed task.

Answer (score 0):

Dispatch queues do not have that capability. You could use `NSOperationQueue` with `NSOperation` to perform background tasks. There is a `cancel` method which you can use to cancel active requests or `cancelAllRequests` to cancel all active requests. There are many tutorials about them on the internet.